# How to fix warning (magento extension) marketplace technical report

Tags: magento

We are uploaded custom extension in marketplace, and found that generated "report". In this report display warning message in

> Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level (a top-level
>   vendor name).

In this issue generated all php files. How to fix this issue.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9iRN.png)